# Start Qt application without user interaction

Tags: qt, ubuntu, embedded

What is the best approach to start an application (Qt) after boot in full screen mode without user interaction.

Some Background:

The application will be running on an embedded device and should be the only interface that the user will see. The operating system is an ARM port of ubuntu. The idea is that the device automatically starts after boot, so that the user have not to care about things like logging in or anything else.

Problems I see are:

- Should there be a special user for this? Since using root isn't a good idea I think.
- How to deal with the password of that user? It wouldn't be very convenient to ask for a password before starting the main application (which in fact to the user seems to be the only application)
- The Application will provide some service functionality, which performs configuration tasks such as Changing IP Address.

So in Short. What are common solutions to fulfil those requirements?

Comment: Concening the password: Does your app needs a password or do you think about user login?

Comment: I think about user login. Because the app needs root privileges in some points.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script inside `/etc/init.d/` in which you start you application in normal user mode. So simply write a shell or bash script to start your application :

**MyScript.sh :**

```
#!/bin/bash

/Path/to/App
```

and move it to the folder:

```
sudo mv MyScript.sh /etc/init.d/
```

Remember to give execution permissions to your script by :

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/MyScript.sh
```

And finally :

```
sudo update-rc.d MyScript.sh defaults
```

You can show your application in fullscreen by calling in your main window constructor :

```
this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
```

If the user has nothing to do with permissions and passwords, you can hard-code the system password in your code and run the necessary commands with that.

Comment: Thank You. If I will use System V for this, will Qt use the X-Server? And isn't hard coding the password in the binary almost the same as running the application as root?